# Child Reactjs component not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components.

- Youtube - handles the searchbar and a container for the search results
- YoutubeSearchResults - as implied... shows the search results after an ajax call has finished

For the first time, when you search for something the results show up fine. But when you search again (query changed or not), the YoutubeSearchResults doesn't update(/re-render) despite it's render function being called and executed (I know because various console.log's show output). I can't figure out why this is happening and no searches seem to be similar to what I'm experiencing.

`Youtube` component:

```
...
render() {
    let body = null;
    if(this.state.data !== null) {
        body = <YoutubeSearchResults data={this.state.data} />
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="youtube-header">
                <form name="youtube-search" action="" onSubmit={this.search.bind(this)} method="post" ref="youtubeSearch">
                    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" autoComplete="off" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="youtube-body" ref="youtubeBody">{body}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
search(e) {
    let self = this;

    ... ajax request ... }, function(data) {
        self.setState({ data: data });
    });
}
```

`YoutubeSearchResults` component:

```
export default class YoutubeSearchResults extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: null,
            currentPage: 0,
            currentVideoId: null
        };
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        this.setState({ currentVideoId: null });
    }
    render() {
        let self = this;
        ...
        return (
            <div>
                {(this.state.data||this.props.data).map(function(obj, key) {
                    return (
                        <div key={key}>
                            <img src={obj.thumbnails.medium} className="youtube-result-thumbnail" />
                            <h3 className="youtube-result-title">{obj.title}</h3>
                            <div className="youtube-result-duration">
                                <span>{obj.contentDetails.duration.toSeconds().parseDuration()}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please post code *here*. I've done that for you this time, but please post it *here*. I'd also suggest giving us only relevant code to your problem as sifting through two whole files is really time consuming and if will discourage many from assisting.

Comment: @AndrewL. Thanks and sorry. Haven't posted here in a while

Comment: Why do you have `this.state.data||this.props.data`? It sounds like your `render` function is stuck pointing to the data in your *state* which is preventing it from using the data in your *props*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. When I was performing a search I was emptying the search results container.

```
search(e) {
    let self = this;

    ... ajax request ... }, function(data) {
        $(self.refs.youtubeBody).empty(); // <-- This was the issue
        self.setState({ data: data });
    });
}
```

Don't know why I didn't think of this before but yeah, I'm presuming it was effectively deleting the YoutubeSearchResults component so when updating the props it wasn't set or something. Mistakingly left it out of my question aswell because I didn't think that was the issue at the time.

So to anyone having a similar issue, make sure you aren't removing the component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update state in child component when it receives new properties:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.setState({ currentVideoId: null, data: newProps.data });
}
```

This update will also trigger re-render.

Comment: Still the same issue. It updates the props/state data but it just doesn't render anything.

Answer (score 0):

In React, if you just need to display something without modifications, avoid storing it in state. That adds needless complications and rendering overhead.

I have removed the superfluous state object for `data`, and removed the ambiguous `(this.state.data||this.props.data)` mapping call. Does the following code work for you?

**YoutubeSearchResults:**

```
export default class YoutubeSearchResults extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPage: 0,
            currentVideoId: null
        };
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        this.setState({ currentVideoId: null });
    }

    render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        // ...
        return (
            <div>
                { data.map((obj, key) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={key}>
                            <img src={obj.thumbnails.medium} className="youtube-result-thumbnail" />
                            <h3 className="youtube-result-title">{obj.title}</h3>
                            <div className="youtube-result-duration">
                                <span>{obj.contentDetails.duration.toSeconds().parseDuration()}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}

            </div>
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```